# Eureka Form Custom Header disappearing / not reloading after navigating back from PushRow

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I have a Custom Header from xib file that is displaying fine. But when I load a PushRow, make a selection, and the form comes back into view, the header is blank - no longer displaying the custom header view. If I scroll the form to where the header is off the screen, then scroll back to where header is visible - the custom header shows up again.

Following the example docs:

```
+++ Section("Unit Data"){ section in

    var header = HeaderFooterView(.nibFile(name: "TableSectionHeader", bundle: nil))

    // Will be called every time the header appears on screen
    header.onSetupView = { view, _ in
    // Commonly used to setup texts inside the view
    // Don't change the view hierarchy or size here!

        view.lblTitle.text = "test"


    }

    section.header = header

    }
```

EDIT: It appears that the .onSetupView() is NOT being called when the form re-appears after selecting an item from a PushRow. It is being called when I scroll the header off the screen and back into view.

XCode 9.2
iPad running iOS 11
Eureka 4.0.1

Thank you.

EDIT - 09/12/2018

I was unable to to figure out why this problem was occurring. I also posted this on the Eureka GitHub issues with no resolution. The work around I used was to re-create my header view programmatically instead of the xib file. Then add the view as per the docs.

```
Section(){ section in
section.header = {
      var header = HeaderFooterView<UIView>(.callback({
          let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
          view.backgroundColor = .red
          return view
      }))
      header.height = { 100 }
      return header
    }()
}
```

A pain for sure - but I had invested heavily in customized Eureka rows and needed this form to work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this, I have the exact same problem?